# Hyperlink in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a RadWindow displaying few details. Along with that I need to add a hyperlink "Test" which on clicking that redirects to sample.aspx page. How can that be done? Below is what I have so far.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div runat="server" id="EventDiv" visible="false" class="Popup">
        <h3>Event Information</h3>
        <table width="250px">
        <tr><td>
        <strong>Event Owner:</strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="EventOwnerLabel"></asp:Label><br />
        <strong>Event Name:</strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="EventNameLabel"></asp:Label><br />
        <strong>Event Date:</strong><asp:Label runat="server" ID="EventDateLabel"></asp:Label><br />
        <a href="ParticipantListing.aspx">Participants Listing</a>
        </td></tr> 
        </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<a href="sample.aspx">Test</a>` ?

Comment: u have already used the hyperlink in your code.. what exactly u want.. i think u need to make it more clear to get ur answer.

Comment: @David :I tried that already. It opens another radwindow of smaller dimension with no contents in it.

Comment: @DeepakSHarma : On Click of Participants Listing(hyperlink) I need the page to redirect from one aspx page to another page here to sample.aspx.

Comment: @user3254765: I guess it's not clear how being a RadWindow changes this.  An anchor tag, by itself, should cause the browser to make a request to that resource and display the response (abandoning the current DOM context).  If there's a component which is breaking that functionality, it's not clear in the question how that's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @David stated use the [anchor tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Usage is like this

```
<a href="sample.aspx">Test</a>
```

Now the href attribute can take in a relative location like show above or something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.Websitething/foo/sample.aspx">Test</a>
```

Comment: It worked. All I had to do was set target=_top since I am trying to redirect from a radwindow to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RadButton (ButtonType="LinkButton" or whatever type you prefer) and on the Click event, perform a

```
Response.Redirect("~/path/sample.aspx", false);
```